# Battery optimization not selectable in Cyanogenmod 13

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, battery

I just installed Cyanogenmod 13 and a couple of Google Apps (the [OpenGApps Micro Package](https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/wiki/Micro-Package)) on a Nexus 4 mako Device. Trying to disable battery optimization for some apps, I found that in the batter settings screen I cannot select `Battery optimization` from the action menu. The item is simply not clickable. One can reach the battery optimization screen from `Settings -> Apps -> Settings -> battery optimization`, too, but then the selector going from `not optimized` to `all apps` is not clickable.

Am I missing some dependency or is this a bug? I have recovered some system settings by `TitaniumBackup`, maybe something was incompatible with CM? (Before, I ran an AOSP marshmallow rom, too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also running CM13 on Nexus 4, with the difference being no GAPPS. The 2 entry points you mentioned works just fine here.

Try a clean flash without restoring settings using TiBu - CM uses a slightly different settings provider from AOSP and it might prove incompatible indeed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, after fiddling around a while I think a clean reflash is the only option. Damn, I hate restoring everything all the time. 
Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @janoliver Well that's the price to pay if you constantly switch ROMs...

Comment: I am not doing that constantly, but yeah. :/